# AngularJS update ng-repeat by param depending on ng-repeat array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a object array=[1,2,3,4,5] with html.What is the proper way to update inside the ng-repeat conditioned by values of array ?. I will put an example :

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="nr in array">
 <p> {{ nr}} </p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="stuff in stuffs(nr)"> {{stuff}} </li>
     </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

i've tried to make a scope function in controller:

```
 scope.stuffs = function(ret){
           ......
 return arrayConditionedbyNr;
}
```

but is throwing an error :

Uncaught Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: ...

can you please guide me in the right direction ?

Comment: The problem is in `......`. If you're recreating a new array every time, then you'll face this problem. Show us a **complete** minimal example.

Comment: could you please show stuffs array?

Comment: If you're using lodash or underscore you can use the `_.range` utility function as seen here: https://lodash.com/docs#range. Given `_.range(4)` it will return [0,1,2,3]

Comment: i've posted at answer my code

Answer (score 0):

perhaps I missed your problem.. but this following plunker works for me
http://plnkr.co/edit/iCepagIKA1OFDjBnB35I?p=preview

perhaps you needed  `<div ng-repeat="test in getArr(item.id) track by $index">`

Answer (score 0):

this is my html :

```
<h2> Last Updates  </h2>
<ul>
<li  ng-repeat="cat in eachCateg"> 
<h3> {{cat}} </h3>
     <ul>

   <li ng-repeat="game in eachGame(cat)"> 
            <p>{{game.id}}</p>  

    </li> -->

    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

this is my controller :

```
applicaton.controller('homeController', ['$scope','$http','$stateParams','$q',function(scope,http,stateParams,q){     


  // server  request with http angular.js, taking category list from JSON for scope.eachCateg
                var getCategories = http.get('data/menu/menu.json')
                 .success(function(result){
                        scope.eachCateg = result.categories;
                 });

               scope.eachGame = function(categ) {

                var httpRequest = http.get('data/games/'+ angular.lowercase(categ)+'/urlThumb.json')
                        .success(function(result){
                            return result;
                        })

                return q.all([httpRequest]).then(function(result){

                               return result[0].data;
                             })

              }
 }]);
```

so this is how i try to update the list and i got that error. It seems to be that it returns me a promise not actual data. How i can make to send me in return the data wanted ?